# Does SVN allows blanks in paths for svn auth file rules?

Tags: svn, authorization

We currently have problems with directories that contain blanks and are part of rules in the svn auth file. So we want to have path based authorization, and have a file that contains the following:

```
[/]
* = rw
[/junk of me]
* = 
me = rw
```

When I clear the authentication data and checkout the root of my repository as `me`, I see the root directory and the sub-directory `junk of me`. When I add a file inside of `junk of me`, and try it to commit as another user, I am allowed to do that. It looks like the rule for `junk of me` does not work at all.

I have tried the following variations, but had no difference at all:

- `[/junk of me]`
- `[/junk\ of\ me]`
- `[/junk%20of%20me]`

Is there a way to have directories with blanks in it, and define rules in the svn auth file?

Comment: Have you setup ParentPath in your Apache Configuration? Or are you serving via svnserve? I would suggest to change your permissin setup to set the *=Empty on the root folder.

Comment: Well, the example I have choosen to show the misfunctioning is not that of the real repository. And yes, we serve by ParentPath in the Apache Configuration, so every repository gets its individual svn auth file.

Comment: That is odd.  This works for me, and I read the source code and found that there is no escape processing for anything within the brackets, it is taken exactly as is.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317074/subversion-authz-path-containing-spaces?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and stumbled upon this page and saw there is no answer given yet.

```
[/junk of me]
* =
```

works perfectly for me.

It would be helpful to check the authz file using svnauthz-validate as my real problem was else where in authz file.