# subversion authz path containing spaces

Tags: svn

How do I setup the authz file for a path which contains spaces?

I tried various methods to escape the spaces but none of them worked.

```
[/"some path"]
[/some%20path]
[/some\ path]
[\"some path\"]
```

Comment: Seems quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374834/does-svn-allows-blanks-in-paths-for-svn-auth-file-rules (... which has no answer as well)

Answer (score 3):

I just checked the svn source code and the file parser (in libsvn_subr/config_file.c:svn_config__parse_file()) allows anything inside the square brackets except a "]", "\n".  In other words, it should work with no escaping whatsoever.

To confirm this I added this rule to a scratch repository:

```
[/a/some really long name.xlsx]
* =
```

As expected, it denied me access.  Furthermore, I checked my production repositories and found several instances of rules like that, so it must work, otherwise I would have gotten complaints before now :)